# Display SD Card Data in ListView android

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Can anybody suggest me how to show all public Data in `ListView` format stored in  my Device's SD Card

Answer (score 1):

How about reusing someone else's class so you write less code?

http://openintents.org/en/filemanager

> Third party developers can use OI File Manager through simple intents to present an "Open file", "Save file", or "Select folder" activity.
>
> The file manager features `PICK_FILE` and `PICK_DIRECTORY` intents:
>
> `Intent intent = new Intent("org.openintents.action.PICK_FILE");
>   startActivityForResult(intent, 1);`
>
> You can provide a pre-selected file or folder by setting data through `setData()` to a file URI, like `"file:///sdcard/notepad.csv"`. The picked file URI can be obtained in `onActivityResult()` through `getData()`.

Comment: This looks like an interesting project.

Comment: I'm using the OI File Manager as a standalone app, it gets feature-updates reasonably often.

Comment: Dear i am unable to add  OI File Manager api in my code can you please Gide

Comment: I am unable to add OI File Manager in my code i need show all SD card public data in a list view format please favor for that

Comment: Follow the link I put and scroll to "Sample application TestFileManager", there are links to their code below. You need to install the APK so that the intent exists.

Comment: please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329454/show-my-android-device-data in need to fetch device SD card all data